# Восстановить файл .bashrc

Tags: archlinux

Пытался добавить JetBrains Rider в PATH, но видимо что-то сделал не так, теперь не работает ни одна команда в терминале. Как мне можно отредактировать этот файл или восстановить?

Comment: Что конкретно означает «не работает», как это проявляется?

Comment: Похоже, [то что вам нужно](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default), [и вот еще](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206151/how-to-restore-default-bashrc-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

запустил вручную vim и написал edit .bashrc, там зашел в конфиг и удалил, что сделал

Comment: Не стоит публиковать уточнения к своему же вопросу в качестве ответа.